# Codename one Tabs Button Styling

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I'm stuck with this [Codename one](http://www.codenameone.com) UI component for two days and still couldn't get a proper solution...I added tabs in my application but when I run the application, the tabs I added don't look as I expected.

**The height of my tab is too big and I want to reduce it.**

See the screenshot of how the tab currently looks below:

[image: screenshot]

And here is the code I'm using in my application:

```
Tabs t = new Tabs();
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
FontImage icon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_QUESTION_ANSWER, s);

Container container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY();
Container container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY();
t.addTab("Tab1", icon1, container1);
t.addTab("Tab2", container2);

hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, t);
hi.show();
```

Comment: Unclear what you expect without your layout code.

Comment: You didn't tell how should they look. You only told how they should **not** look.

Comment: look at that code and tell me whats wrong with this code..

Comment: the height of tab-bar is little high so it is looking diffrent from native tabs

Comment: Provide more clarity in your question in future. I've edited the question, have a look and always follow this concept. Also, visit this page to learn how to ask good questions... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your GUI Builder and style the `Tab` Uiid to reduce the padding as necessary:

Style the Unselected, Selected and Pressed to have the same padding size, see the image below to know the key elements to touch:

[image: Tab Uiid Styling]